# Need to call back an array in Google Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, google-apps-script

I am attempting to send an array through the callback and having no luck. Let me explain my intent and perhaps an expert out there can send me some ideas for how to solve this dilema.

I have creates a spreadsheet that collects data. I then have a UI script which pulls row data into a flex table for a user to process by clicking a checkbox. I created a separate flex table that contains the checkboxes which the user checks or leaves blank. In my script I need to send an array that contains the checkbox condition. Why? Because I also need the row # or array placement that I can push to the spreadsheet to send the correct updated status for the data.

The script only pulls data that needs action into the UI. Thus I may be acting on Rows 1,3,4,5,and 8 of the spreadsheet but on the UI flextable the row that correspond to the data are rows 1,2,3,4,5 thus the row assignments don't match. BUT if I use an array I can capture that the row pulled was 1,3,4,5,and 8 and then update the spreadsheet accordingly.

However, that is the problem when I try to callback my array labeled offset[inc] I cannot get it to work I get run errors of cannot find method addcallback and cannot get it to work.

Recommendations on how to send an array through the addcallback method or alternate recommendations would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Sean Nutzman

```
function doGet(e){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  //Create Caption Panel
  var captionPanel = app.createCaptionPanel('Detention   Attendance').setWidth('350px').setHeight('75px').setStyleAttribute('fontWeight', 'bold').setStyleAttribute('fontSize', '24px');

  //Add a widget to caption panel
  captionPanel.add(app.createLabel("Please enter attendance for Detention by clicking the     checkbox next to the student's name if they were present. Then click Sumbit."));

  //add the caption panel to the application  
  app.add(captionPanel);

  var panel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  var flexTable = app.createFlexTable().setStyleAttribute('border', '2px solid black')
      .setStyleAttribute('borderCollapse','collapse')
      .setBorderWidth(2)
      .setCellSpacing(50)
      .setCellPadding(6); 

  //Get Data from spreadsheet
  var spreadsheetId = '0Aup0nXQ4K-pydFREb1FFcTFYX3lOenNQenR1Q01jQ1E';   //Change this to     the Spreadsheet ID
  var dataArray = getData(spreadsheetId);
  var inc = 1;
 //Load data into table cells
   for (var row = 0; row<dataArray.length; row++) {
      var booleanCheck =  dataArray[row] [17];
      var offset = new Array();


      if (booleanCheck == "" || booleanCheck == "Date Served") {
         if (row > 0) {
         Logger.log("Row value = " + row);      
         var ticketDate = dataArray[row] [0];
         var dateStamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(ticketDate), "America/Chicago", "MM/dd/yyyy");

         dataArray[row] [0] = dateStamp;
         var ticketDate2 = dataArray[row] [16];
         var dateStamp2 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(ticketDate2), "America/Chicago", "MM/dd/yyyy");
         dataArray[row] [16] = dateStamp2;
         flexTable.setText(row, 1, dataArray[row][2].toString());
         flexTable.setText(row, 0, dataArray[row][0].toString());
         flexTable.setText(row, 2, dataArray[row][16].toString());  
         offset[inc] = row; inc++;
         Logger.log('Inc variable = ' + inc);
         Logger.log('Offset = ' + offset[inc-1]);
     } else {
         Logger.log("Inside ELSE row is not > 0");
         Logger.log("Row value here = " + row);
         flexTable.setText(0, 1, "Student's Name").setStyleAttribute(0, 1, 'fontWeight', 'bold');
         flexTable.setText(0, 0, "Date Assigned").setStyleAttribute(0, 0, 'fontWeight', 'bold');
         flexTable.setText(0, 2, "Date Delinquent").setStyleAttribute(0, 2, 'fontWeight', 'bold');    
       }  
     }
   }
  Logger.log(offset);
  panel.add(flexTable);

  var check1 = app.createCheckBox().setName('ch1');  
  var check2 = app.createCheckBox().setName('ch2');
  var check3 = app.createCheckBox().setName('ch3');
  var check4 = app.createCheckBox().setName('ch4');
  var check5 = app.createCheckBox().setName('ch5');
  var check6 = app.createCheckBox().setName('ch6');
  var check7 = app.createCheckBox().setName('ch7');
  var check8 = app.createCheckBox().setName('ch8');
  var check9 = app.createCheckBox().setName('ch9');
  var submitButton = app.createButton("Submit");
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('updateStatus');
  handler.addCallbackElement(check1)
    .addCallbackElement(check2)
    .addCallbackElement(check3)
    .addCallbackElement(check4)
    .addCallbackElement(check5)
    .addCallbackElement(check6)
    .addCallbackElement(check7)
    .addCallbackElement(check8)
    .addCallbackElement(check9)
    .addCallbackElement(offset);
  submitButton.addClickHandler(handler);
  handler.addCallbackElement(check1)
     .addCallbackElement(check2)
     .addCallbackElement(check3)
     .addCallbackElement(check4)
     .addCallbackElement(check5)
     .addCallbackElement(check6)
     .addCallbackElement(check7)
     .addCallbackElement(check8)
     .addCallbackElement(check9)
     .addCallbackElement(offset);

  var table = app.createGrid(11,1).setStyleAttribute('border', '2px solid black')
      .setStyleAttribute('borderCollapse','collapse')
      .setBorderWidth(2)
      .setWidth('75px')
      .setCellSpacing(5)
      .setCellPadding(6);
   table.setStyleAttributes({textAlign: "center"});
   table.setStyleAttribute('fontWeight', 'bold').setText(0, 0, 'Attendance');
   table.setWidget(1,0, (check1));
   table.setWidget(2,0, (check2));
   table.setWidget(3,0, (check3));
   table.setWidget(4,0, (check4));
   table.setWidget(5,0, (check5));
   table.setWidget(6,0, (check6));
   table.setWidget(7,0, (check7));
   table.setWidget(8,0, (check8));
   table.setWidget(9,0, (check9));
   table.setWidget(10,0,(submitButton));

   panel.add(table);
   app.add(panel);
   app.close();
   return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is to convert the array to a string and write it on the [widget's tag](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/check-box#setTag%28String%29).
Then I can retrieve it using `e.parameter.widgetName_tag` in the handler function. At this point I can split it to get back the array : `e.parameter.widgetName_tag.split(',');`

You'll have to be careful when choosing the `join` and `split` character since your data might contain a comma (which is the default separator in arrays)... I often use a | or any other 'uncommon' character (Ë,Í;∆)  in combination with `join('∆')` and `split('∆')` so I'm sure I get the array back as it should.

Of course the widget must be included in the `callBackElement` but this is easily achieved by using the highest level parent UiApp element as `callBackElement`.

Last comment : try to use widget Ids that will simplify your life ... for example use Ids containing a number that corresponds to the array index ( chk0, chk1, chk2...) so that you can easily retrieve the numeric value to use in your handler function using something like this :

`Number(e.parameter.source.replace(/[a-z]/ig,''))`

which will give you a number that identifies which `checkBox` is the origin of the handler call so you can write :

```
var arrayElement = e.parameter.widgetName_tag.split(',')[Number(e.parameter.source.replace(/[a-z]/ig,''))];
```

Comment: Could you not maybe convert to json before writing to the tag? Might save problems with join and split!

Comment: That's indeed also a pretty nice way to do it. More 'academic' maybe :-)  thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = ['foo','poo'];
var arrayString = JSON.stringify(array);
```

At that point, just attach arrayString to a callback element and voila!  Then in the handlerFunction, you access it out with e.parameter.arrayString and then parse it to return it back to an array like so:

```
var array = JSON.parse(e.parameter.arrayName);
//array = ['foo','poo']
```